# How to redirect to a html page in a same folder as flask file?

Tags: python, html, redirect, flask

I want when i go to localhost:8081 for flask to redirect me to file main.html, how can I do that? Here is the code i started with.

```
from flask import *
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def start():
    return render_template("main.html")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8081,debug=True)
```

The page main.html is in the same folder as file that contains this code.

Comment: Why does it be to be in the same directory? Flask expects templates to be in a templates directory.

Comment: @DanielRoseman and where is tamplates directory?

Comment: @JaSamSale: You create it in the same location as your Python files.

Answer (score 0):

This [page](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/#simple-packages) in the documentation tells you how to structure your Flask project. Flask will look for templates in the templates folder when you render a template with `render_template`